# How to catch mouse over event of QListWidget in pyqt5?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qlistwidget

How to make use of mouse hovering event when user hover over items inside the qlistWidget in order to display a toolTip.

I was able to show the toolTip on select the currentItem, what i nned now is not selecting but just hovering.

The code below show the python script that create a GUI interface where user select path and the system read its content in order to find matching expression after comparing between user input and text content.

## updated question :

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QCheckBox, QColorDialog, QDialog,
                             QErrorMessage, QFileDialog, QFontDialog, QFrame, QGridLayout,
                             QInputDialog, QLabel, QLineEdit, QMessageBox, QPushButton, QMenu)

#from PyQt5.QtCore import QDir, Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import pdfviewer

import os,pathlib
from pathlib import Path
import re

import json,datetime,time
from collections import defaultdict

import docx
import PyPDF2


class pdfViewer(QtWidgets.QMainWindow,pdfviewer.Ui_PdfPreviewWindow):


    def __init__(self,PdfPreviewObj):


        pdfviewer.Ui_PdfPreviewWindow.__init__(self)

        self.PdfPreviewObj =PdfPreviewObj 
        self.setupUi(PdfPreviewObj)
        self.PdfPreviewObj.show()
        self.pushButtonSearch.setEnabled(False)
        self.pushButtonOpenFolder.clicked.connect(self.setExistingDirectory)
        self.pushButtonSearch.clicked.connect(self.FilteredListSearch)
        self.listWidgetPDFlist.clicked.connect(self.MatchFunc)
        #self.listWidgetPDFlist.doubleClicked.connect(self.OpenFileDirectory)
        self.listWidgetPDFlist.doubleClicked.connect(self.OpenTheSelectedFile)
        #self.listWidgetPDFlist.enterEvent()

        self.hoverItem = None
        self.listWidgetPDFlist.viewport().setMouseTracking(True)
        self.listWidgetPDFlist.viewport().installEventFilter(self)        

        #####################################

    #added

    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        if self.listWidgetPDFlist.viewport() == obj and event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.MouseMove:
            it = self.listWidgetPDFlist.itemAt(event.pos())
            if self.hoverItem != it:
                message = it.text("test tooltip") # <--- place the message here
                QtWidgets.QToolTip.showText(QtGui.QCursor.pos(), 
                                                message, 
                        self.listWidgetPDFlist.viewport(), 
                        self.listWidgetPDFlist.visualItemRect(it))
                self.hoverItem = it

        return QtWidgets.QMainWindow.eventFilter(self, obj, event)

    #def enterEvent(self,QEvent):
        ## here the code for mouse hover

        #Item=self.listWidgetPDFlist.currentItem().text()
        #parentFile =Path().resolve().parent
        #selectedFile = os.path.join(parentFile,Item)

        #self.listWidgetPDFlist.setStyleSheet("""QToolTip { 
                                       #background-color: black; 
                                       #color: white;                            
                                       #border-radius: 10px;
                                       #border: black solid 1px;
                                       #font: 12px
                                       #}""")

        #print("current row = {}".format(self.listWidgetPDFlist.currentRow()))

        ##{
        ##color: #ffffff; 
            ##background-color: #2a82da; 
            ##border: 1px solid white;
        ##}

        #toolTipResult = self.listWidgetPDFlist.setToolTip(selectedFile)
        #return toolTipResult        



    def FileListSelected(self):             # Function to select the desired file from the list in the left pane

        Item=self.listWidgetPDFlist.currentItem().text()
        parentFile =Path().resolve().parent

        selectedFile = os.path.join(parentFile,Item)

        return selectedFile

    def ReadingFileContent(self,Item):      # Function to read the file content

        if self.lineEdit_Ext.text()=='pdf'or self.rdBtn_pdf.isChecked():
            try:
                with open(Item,'rb')as fw:
                    read_pdf = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(fw)
                    PDF_of_pages = read_pdf.pages
                    fullText = []
                    for page in (PDF_of_pages):
                        fullText.append(page.extractText())
                        self.textString= ' <br/> '.join(fullText)                        
            except:
                self.textEdit_PDFpreview.insertHtml('File Not Found')
                pass
        elif (self.lineEdit_Ext.text()=='docx' or self.lineEdit_Ext.text()=='doc' or self.rdBtn_docx.isChecked()):
            try:
                Doc = docx.Document(Item)
                fullText = []
                for para in Doc.paragraphs:
                    fullText.append(para.text)
                    self.textString= ' <br/> '.join(fullText)

            except:
                self.textEdit_PDFpreview.insertHtml('File Not Found')
                pass          
        else:
            try:
                with open(Item) as fw:    
                    self.textString=fw.read()
            except:
                self.textEdit_PDFpreview.insertHtml('No Match Found')
                pass                
        return self.textString




    def MatchFunc(self):            # Function to highlight the found criteria and display it in the right pane

        self.textEdit_PDFpreview.clear()
        x = self.lineEditSearch.text().strip()
        TextString=self.ReadingFileContent(self.FileListSelected())


        if ' ' in x:
            y=list(x.split(sep=" "))
            for z in y:
                RepX='<u><b style="color:#FF0000">'+z+'</b></u>'
                self.textEdit_PDFpreview.clear()
                if z in TextString:
                    TextString=self.HighLight(z,TextString,RepX)

        else:

            RepX='<u><b style="color:#FF0000">'+x+'</b></u>'


                ##added
            self.textEdit_PDFpreview.clear()

            if x in TextString:
                self.HighLight(x,TextString,RepX)

    def HighLight(self,x,TextString,RepX):
        thematch=TextString.replace(x,RepX)
        TheCount=TextString.count(x)
        self.textEdit_PDFpreview.insertHtml(str(thematch))
        return thematch     

    def setExistingDirectory(self): 
        self.listWidgetPDFlist.clear()
        self.fileList=[]
        dialog = QDialog()
        options = QFileDialog.DontResolveSymlinks | QFileDialog.ShowDirsOnly 
        Folder = QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(dialog, "Open Folder" ,options=options)
        self.checkPath(Folder)


    def checkPath(self,folder):         # Funtion to check the given path for the wanted extension (Files)

        try:
            directory=folder


            whichChecked=""
            for root,dirs,files in os.walk(directory):

                for filename in files:
                    if len(self.lineEdit_Ext.text())>0:
                        self.lineEdit_Ext.setStyleSheet("background-color:white")
                        self.lineEdit_Ext.setPlaceholderText("Enter The Filetype Extention Here")

                        if filename.endswith(self.lineEdit_Ext.text()):
                            self.fullPath=os.path.join(root,filename)
                            print(self.fullPath)
                            self.fileList.append(self.fullPath)

                    elif self.rdBtn_txt.isChecked() and filename.endswith("txt"):
                        self.fullPath=os.path.join(root,filename)
                        self.fileList.append(self.fullPath)
                        whichChecked="txt Ext was Selected"
                        print(fullPath)

                    elif self.rdBtn_pdf.isChecked() and filename.endswith("pdf"):
                        self.fullPath=os.path.join(root,filename)
                        self.fileList.append(self.fullPath)
                        whichChecked="pdf Ext was Selected"
                        print(self.fullPath)

                    elif self.rdBtn_docx.isChecked() and filename.endswith("docx") or filename.endswith("doc") :
                        self.fullPath=os.path.join(root,filename)

                        p = pathlib.Path(self.fullPath)
                        oneDir = os.path.join(*p.parts[-2:])

                        self.fileList.append(oneDir)
                        whichChecked="docx - doc Ext was Selected"

                        print(self.fullPath)
                        print(oneDir)


                    if len(self.fileList) > 0:
                        self.lineEdit_Ext.setStyleSheet("bacground-color:white;")
                        self.lineEdit_Ext.setPlaceholderText("{0}".format(whichChecked))
                    else:
                        self.lineEdit_Ext.setStyleSheet("background-color:Red")
                        self.lineEdit_Ext.setPlaceholderText("No Ext is Specified")                            


            self.ListFilesInViewer(self.fileList)           # add the list into the  listWidgetPDFlist 

            self.pushButtonSearch.setEnabled(True)

            return folder

        except Exception as e:
            print("this error occure {0}".format(e))

    def FilteredListSearch(self):               # Function to filter the list of files to the one that contains the criteria

        FilteredList=[]

        for Item in self.fileList:
            user_input=self.lineEditSearch.text().strip()
            print(user_input)
            textString=self.ReadingFileContent(Item)
            StrList=list(textString.splitlines())
            print("str list {}".format(StrList))
            #added

            if ' ' in user_input:
                SearchList=list(user_input.split(sep=" "))
                if '' in SearchList:
                    SearchList.remove(" ")
                CommonList=list(set(SearchList) & set(StrList))
                if len(CommonList)==len(SearchList):                # All the words in the list
                    FilteredList.append(Item)
                if len(CommonList)>1:                               # Any word of the list
                    pass

            else:
                if user_input in textString:
                    FilteredList.append(Item)  


            self.ListFilesInViewer(FilteredList)


    def ListFilesInViewer(self,Files):              # Function to list all the files in the Left pane 
        self.listWidgetPDFlist.addItems(Files)
        self.lineEditTotalPDFnumber.setText(str(self.listWidgetPDFlist.count()))        #Set the total number of existing  PDF files in the requested path

    def OpenTheSelectedFile(self):          # Function to open the selected file
        os.startfile(self.FileListSelected())  

    def OpenFileDirectory(self):
        MyDir=os.path.dirname(self.FileListSelected())
        os.startfile(MyDir)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    PdfPreviewWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    pdfViewerUi = pdfViewer(PdfPreviewWindow)
    PdfPreviewWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**note** :

I deleted  **pdfviewer.py** class  because I reached the maximum number of allowed characters in the body.

Comment: i need to show the full path for the hovered file.
this is working on selecting the file not on hovering ... when the user hover over an item of the qlistWidget nothing is displayed

Comment: i did not understand your last comment

Comment: yes i know  ... what i want is to show this  when user hover over an item of the qlistWidget

Comment: i was trying to minimize the code to focus on the problem because there are other functions that get the path and display the files in the qlistWidget.  so if you want i can  display  the related functions

Comment: pdfviewer.py is the converted file of the pdfviewer.ui (where i create the GUI in QT_creator)

Comment: i added the function that fill the items  in the QListWidget

Comment: According to what I see ListFilesInViewer that is the method you mention is called in checkPath, but I do not see where you call checkPath. Your code is incomplete. I'm getting tired of telling you.

Comment: i edit my question and add the function that call checkPath function

Comment: Can I execute your code without missing things? I do not think so. When you provide an [MCVE] I will do it, at least the code I show is workable, I hope it helps you.

Comment: Did my solution work for you?